# Is it possible to visually group items on the theme customizer?

Tags: theme-development, customization, theme-customizer

My theme customizer is getting bigger and I think from an UX perspective would be nice to visually group some similar items. Is there way to do that? Something like put a divider or playing with CSS among the items or even put them into 'parent' sections.

Comment: the question you asked is too brood. Sure you can do everything with css and jquery if you fail to inject the proper HTML.

Comment: @MarkKaplun The question is fine. Conceptual problems are on topic and very welcome here.

Comment: @toscho, if you say so, still for question that are "Is there a way to do X" the answer is almost always a simple "yes", and if X is brood then that might be the only answer anyone will bother to write.

Comment: I guess you are already [adding a new section](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API#Adding_a_New_Section)?